# How to access form.email?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I am looking to slightly edit the default password_reset_form.html provided by django-registration.  The current output is:

[image: Reset Page]

I would like to remove the 'E-mail address:' label and put a 'placeholder' text inside the input box.  How can you accomplish this?  I can't seem to find documentation on form.email or form.email.errors.

Password_reset_form.html is shown below:

```
{% extends "registration/registration_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Reset password" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>
    {% blocktrans %}
    Forgot your password? Enter your email in the form below and we'll send you instructions for creating a new one.
    {% endblocktrans %}
</p>
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.email.errors }}
    <p><label for="id_email">{% trans 'E-mail address:' %}</label> {{ form.email }} <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Reset my password' %}" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}


{# This is used by django.contrib.auth #}
```

Comment: One obvious route is to copy the source code of the rendered html. Then remove `{{ form.email }}` and put the raw html tag and add a placeholder to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks).

So your code will look like this.

```
{% extends "registration/registration_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Reset password" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>
    {% blocktrans %}
    Forgot your password? Enter your email in the form below and we'll send you instructions for creating a new one.
    {% endblocktrans %}
</p>
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.email.errors }}
    <p> {{ form.email|attr:"placeholder:E-mail address:"  }} <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Reset my password' %}" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}


{# This is used by django.contrib.auth #}
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a really useful package. Do I need to add the path somewhere in particular? I am getting this error. 'widget_tweaks' is not a valid tag library: Template library widget_tweaks not found, tried django.templatetags.widget_tweaks,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.widget_tweak‌​s,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.widget_tweaks

Comment: first you need to install it.
pip install django-widget-tweaks
Then add ‘widget_tweaks’ to INSTALLED_APPS